# Reload current page in Ionic 4, angular 7

Tags: angular7, ionic4

I'm trying to build a fallback for those that are running the APP with no Internet connection.
In mypage.ts, i have the following:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Network } from '@ionic-native/network/ngx';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-contacto',
  templateUrl: './contacto.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./contacto.page.scss'],
})
export class ContactoPage implements OnInit {
  constructor(private network: Network) {
        // watch network for a connection
        this.network.onConnect().subscribe(() => {
          document.getElementById("netOFF").style.display="none";
         // document.getElementById("netRel").style.display="none";
          console.log('Internet ON');
        });
         // watch network for a disconnection
         this.network.onDisconnect().subscribe(() => {
          document.getElementById("netON").style.display="none";
          console.log('Sin conexión a Internet');
        });
        function reload() {
          this.ionViewWillEnter();
      }
      }
  ngOnInit() { }
}
```

My html file looks like this:

```
<ion-content>
    <div id="netON">
        <iframe src="https://www.domain.es/" style="top:57px; left:0; bottom:0; right:0; width:100%; height:100%; border:none; margin:0; padding: 0; overflow:hidden; z-index:999999;"></iframe>
      </div>
<div id="netOFF"><ion-img src="/assets/img/net.png" style="display:block; width:100%; height:100%; object-fit: cover; z-index:999999;"></ion-img>
</div>
  </ion-content>
  <ion-footer id="netRel" (click)="reload()">
      <ion-toolbar color="danger">
          <ion-icon name="exit" slot="start"></ion-icon>
        <ion-title>Reintentar</ion-title>
      </ion-toolbar>
    </ion-footer>
```

So, the contact form is an iframe, if the phone doesn't have an Internet connection, **netON** (the iFrame), will be hidden, if the phone have an Internet connection, the Iframe will be shown.

Additionally, i have a button **(click)="reload()"**, for those that had no connection and they're back Online in order to reload the page.

**I need a way to reload the page on user click for Ionic 4.**

> Please note that i made some changes in order to test the button
>   action on click so i made it visible, but it's hidden if no Internet,
>   and the picture as well.

Comment: please try this my code : [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50115582/how-to-refresh-a-page-on-ionic-3-ionic-angular-5/50115882#50115882]

Comment: Hello, thanks but i have the latest ionic and angular, i don't have navCtrl, i have angular router instead.

Answer (score 2):

your code doesn't show what data you actually load on the call of the reload() method.
**Note: your reload() function shouldn't be in your constructor. It should be out of the constructor on the same level as ngOnInit() { } **

So if there is data to be fetched, kindly call the functions/methods inside the reload() method like this to re-fetch and update the view:

```js
reload() {
    this.getData();
}

// where getData() method is what does the actually loading of the data like:

getData() {
    this.apiService.fetchData()
    .subscribe(
        data => {
            this.items = data;
    }, err => {});
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you wanna **reload** your whole page, use this code.

```
window.location.reload();
```